# How do I break out of a stuck lock screen?

Tags: macos

On a MacBook Pro (the office's, I'm a noob), I started the upgrade process from Mavericks to El-Capitan from the app store.

After a while, the screen locked as, I assume, is usual. But now I cannot log back in. I typed my user's password in and hit enter, nothing. I tried hitting the the little arrow button to the right of the password and nothing. It's not frozen as the mouse still works, no beachball, I can clear the password. I clicked on the *Cancel* and *Switch User* buttons which appear to activate, but then did nothing.

That was the case for quite a while, then I tried clicking the *Switch User* button again, and the desktop rotated like a cube and now gives me a light grey screen.

Answer (score 1):

Just <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Power</kbd>'d it. Install hadn't actually started (only download had), so was ready to upgrade after reboot.